Cannot make simple short circuit with CircuitLabs


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The following circuit should make short circuit, but the voltage meter is still showing 5 volts? I cannot understand, how is this possible. Is this a bug with the simulator?

No this is not a bug in a simulator. Simply VS is an ideal voltage source, hence it can provide infinity amount of current. In the simulation, the voltage source current is equal to 5x10E^15A

CircuitLabs has a lot of unknowns hidden but if you assume the switch is zero ohms which it isn't and the voltage source is ideal 0 Ohms then the switch current will be V/Rsw=I and the meter reads the ideal VS.  In order to be realistic, there must be defined Rs for all components.
This is why I prefer Falstad Simulator which even forbids putting switchs, voltage sources and caps in parallel unless you add ESR for a cap.
This is because 0 ESR gives infinite current on any initial condition and is only used in logic diagrams and is not realistic.

You have asked the simulator to solve a problem that does not have a proper answer. No wonder the results are strange.
I suspect that a close examination of the documentation would find that voltage sources have a small series resistance, or switches a minimum resistance, or some such thing.

Infinities and dividing by zero are not meaningful in formulas for electric circuits. So you can't simulate them.
The circuit is impossible, because it would mean there would be simultaneously an ideal 5V supply with 5V over it, and an ideal switch with 0 ohms resistance which would mean there is 0V over the switch.
You can't have 5V and 0V simultaneously on the shorted nodes as it is impossible to have 5V over 0 ohms resistance, even at infinite current.
